# Using \xrightarrow and \downarrow

Tags: arrows

I am trying to denote a set of conversions using arrows. The following doesn't compile when `\downarrow` and `\xrightarrow` is used in the same line. Could someone help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\downarrow}{b}$ \quad
$\overset{\overset{\text{text}}{\downarrow}}{b}$
\[ 
A\xrightarrow{\text{a}}\overset{\downarrow}{B}\xrightarrow{\text{a}}C 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you by chance looking for a commutative diagram?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @samcarter missing $ compile error on sharelatex

Comment: can you add a link to the sharlatex project?

Comment: works here with pdflatex from tex live 2016.

Comment: My impression is that you're looking at the wrong code in your project, because this snippet has nothing that can cause an error.

Comment: I hadn't used `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`. I doubt whether this caused the error.

Comment: The error occurred because I used `\text{a_{n}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
I do not get an error:\\
$\overset{\downarrow}{b}$ \quad
$\overset{\overset{\text{text}}{\downarrow}}{b}$
\[ 
A\xrightarrow{\text{a}}\overset{\downarrow}{B}\xrightarrow{\text{a}}C 
\]
But I am wondering if you are secretly looking for a commutative diagram.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0.4cm,column sep=0.4cm]
\arrow[d] &  & \text{text}\arrow[d] \\
b  & D\arrow[d,"\text{text}"] & b \\
A \arrow[r,"a"]& B \arrow[r,"a"] & C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
I understand that this may not be the diagram you want, but if you let me know
how it should look like I'll be happy to adjust.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about commutative diagrams. Thanks!! I just want to add a D above the downarrow pointing to B.Also,I wish to add a text to the right of downarrow

Comment: @Natasha I updated my answer. Is that closer to what you want?